# Is there a more elegant way to nest arrays in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, matrix

I am translating a matrix from a C++ project that looks like this:

```
static int grad4[][4] = {{0,1,1,1}, {0,1,1,-1}, {0,1,-1,1}, {0,1,-1,-1},
{-1,1,1,0}, {-1,1,-1,0}, {-1,-1,1,0}, {-1,-1,-1,0}};
```

and basically the way to do it in C# is nesting arrays, right?, so the array looks like this:

```
static int[][] grad4 = new int[][]{
new int[]{0,1,1,1},new int[]{0,1,1,-1},new int[]{0,1,-1,1},new int[]{0,1,-1,-1},
new int[]{-1,1,1,0},new int[]{-1,1,-1,0},new int[]{-1,-1,1,0},new int[]{-1,-1,-1,0}};
```

That is fine if the matrix is not too big, but the project has some matrix with more than 80 columns. Is there a more simple way to initialize a matrix? Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287601%28v=vs.71%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) you should be able to write

```
static int[,] grad4 = new int[,]{{0,1,1,1}, {0,1,1,-1}, {0,1,-1,1}, {0,1,-1,-1},
                                 {-1,1,1,0}, {-1,1,-1,0}, {-1,-1,1,0}, {-1,-1,-1,0}};
```

This declares a multi-dimensional array. A jagged array (`int[][]`) must be initialized as you described.

Answer (score 6):

probably you should think about storing your data in a multidimensional array instad of a jagged array

```
//multidimensional Array
int[,] multi = { { 7, 2, 6, 1 }, { 3, 5, 4, 8 }, { 6, 2, 9, 50 } };


//array of arrays (jagged arrays) 
int[][] jagged = new int[][] { 
                  new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, 
                  new int[] { 11, 12 }, 
                  new int[] { 21, 22, 23 }
                  };
```